# Android Google plus login, cannot get username

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm implementing google plus login in android. I have been following along with the tutorial
[developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started)

In `PeopleApi` is when i call `Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient)` is always get null.

I have correctly configured `SHA` at `console.developers.google.com` and even filled in the `consent screen`

Please help, i have tried everything.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

MainActivity file

```
package dailyblog.ebt.com.dailyapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.CommonStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.People;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.PersonBuffer;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult> {


    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    private boolean mSignInClicked;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
    private PlusClient mPlusClient;

   // Button btnsign;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).
                addConnectionCallbacks(this).
                addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).
                addApi(Plus.API).
                addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).
                addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE).
                build();


        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (connec != null &&
                (connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) ||
                (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to the internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ||
                connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ) {
            //Not connected.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not connected to the internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Log.d("onstat","sau");
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            // Store the ConnectionResult so that we can use it later when the user clicks
            // 'sign-in'.
            mConnectionResult = result;

            if (mSignInClicked) {
                // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to resolve all
                // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }
    }

    private void resolveSignInError() {

        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                startIntentSenderForResult(mConnectionResult.getResolution().getIntentSender(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
                // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {

            if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
            }

            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button
                && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mSignInClicked = true;
            if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
                resolveSignInError();
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "User already connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient,null).setResultCallback(this);

        String personName="Unknown";

        Toast.makeText(this, "username is -> " + personName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);




        Toast.makeText(this, "email -> " + Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            Toast.makeText(this, "username is -> " + personName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(People.LoadPeopleResult peopleData) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onteid!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    }
}
```